# UI Sketching software for Mac

Tags: macos, user-interface

Is there any application for UI sketching on Mac OS X? Something like SketchFlow on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really, really, really (you get the idea) love [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/). It's cross-platform, via Adobe Air.

Answer (score 9):

Omnigraffle is a very nice UI drafting system.

Extra stencils: http://graffletopia.com/

Comment: Why this answer is being downvoted? "I don't like Omnigraffle" != "This is not a useful answer"

Comment: Yea I don't know why it would be down voted either, it is a very useful UI designer

Comment: In addition to that you get one of the best apps out there for the mac +1

Comment: Omnigraffle seems to be very good, are there special software UI stencils?

Comment: @totocaster - Yep. Check out http://graffletopia.com/ theres tons of stencils for anything imaginable.

Answer (score 4):

[Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/desktop) is cross-platform and is a very solid sketching program.

Answer (score 3):

[ForeUI](http://www.ForeUI.com) is worth trying.  It can run in Mac OS and you can freely switch your design style between sketch and Mac OS look.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Wireframe Sketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com/), which is built atop the Eclipse platform, so is inherently cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but you might also look at EasyPrototype: http://www.extremeplanner.com/easyprototype/

Answer (score 0):

[MockupScreens](http://mockupscreens.com) runs on Mac (I am developer). You might check it out, it's pretty popular. It's low fidelity, aimed for analysts and UX people, ie. non-programmer "civilians".

And here is the most comprehensive list of mockup tools I know of, some of them run on Mac:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools